# Loop through a directory with Grep (newbie)

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I'm trying to do loop through the current directory that the script resides in, which has a bunch of files that end with _list.txt I would like to grep each file name and assign it to a variable and then execute some additional commands and then move on to the next file until there are no more _list.txt files to be processed.

I assume I want something like:

```
while file_name=`grep "*_list.txt" *`
do
   Some more code
done
```

But this doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions of how to accomplish this newbie task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you problem correctly, you don't need a `grep`. You can just do:

```
for file in *_list.txt
do
# use $file, like echo $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is one of the most useful commands of Unix.  You must comprehend it well; see some useful [examples here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/).  As far as your current requirement, I think following code will be useful:

```
for file in *.* 
do
  echo "Happy Programming"
done
```

In place of `*.*` you can also use regular expressions.  For more such useful examples, see [First Time Linux](http://linux.activityworkshop.net/programming/bash.html), or read all `grep` options at your terminal using `man grep`.

Comment: Please do not write in SMS-style abbreviations; use full English (American) words, please.  ('u must comprehend it well' and 'at ur terminal' are not really acceptable here.)